# calculate related cells if value changes in any of the related cells

Tags: worksheet-function, macros

I have a column with 5 cells that are related by formula:

```
A1=A2+A3+A4+A5 
A2=A1-A3-A4-A5 
A3=a1-a2-a4-a5
a4=a1-a2-a3-a5
a5=a1-a2-a3-a4
```

1. I need a macro that will automatically calculate all cells A1:A5 if user enters value in any one of the cells in this range. if any cell in range A1:A5 is > 0 then calculate each cell a1:A5 based on the formulas. i am using this code to calculate A1

   If cell.Value > 0 Then
       Application.EnableEvents = False
           range.Cells(1, 1).Formula = "=A2+A3+A4+A5"
       Application.EnableEvents = True

but i couldn't figure how to automatae calculations in a2:a5

2. I have set values for A1:A5 to 0 by default (i need to use command button that  sets values to 0). i use the following macro

   For Each cell In range
    If cell.Value = 0 Then
      MsgBox ("Enter value other than 0 in any cell in range A1:A5")

If all values in A1:A5 are 0 then I will need to click "ok" on pop up message box 5 times! 
How do i change a macro that if All cells in range a1:A5 are 0 then only one message box pops up (i will need to click ok to get rid of it)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We can use an **array of single cell ranges** rather than formulas:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A(1 To 5) As Range

    Set A(1) = Range("A1")
    Set A(2) = Range("A2")
    Set A(3) = Range("A3")
    Set A(4) = Range("A4")
    Set A(5) = Range("A5")

    If Intersect(Range("A1:A5"), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False
        A(1) = A(2) + A(3) + A(4) + A(5)
        A(2) = A(1) - A(3) - A(4) - A(5)
        A(3) = A(1) - A(2) - A(4) - A(5)
        A(4) = A(1) - A(2) - A(3) - A(5)
        A(5) = A(1) - A(2) - A(3) - A(4)
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

*(avoiding formulas avoids recursive confusion)*

**EDIT#1:**

The routine first re-calculates **A1** based on the values in **A2** through **A5**.
The routine then re-calculates **A2** based on the *new* value in **A1** and the old values in **A3** through **A5**.
The routine then re-calculates **A3** based on the *new* values in **A1** and **A2** and the old values in **A4** and **A5**.
The routine then re-calculates **A4** based on the *new* values in **A1** through **A3** and the old value in **A5**.
The routine then re-calculates the value in **A5** based on the *new* values in **A1** through **A4**.
This is exactly the order you specified in your question!

Comment: Thank you! how do i assign this macro to a form control button?

Comment: @lioliklev  This is ***Event driven***.  It will run automatically when the user changes any cells in the range *A1:A5*

Comment: it does calculate everything, if i have values in A2:A5 ic calculates A1 but then if i change A1 to a different value to see what A2:A5 will be, it forces A1 back to sum of A2:A5. So if i have value "1" in A2:A5 then A1 is "4". now if i change A1 to 3 - i want to see what values will be in A2:A5 based on A1=3, but it bounces back to A1=4.

Comment: @lioliklev  **you are correct!**  Se my **EDIT#1**

Comment: so what would be the code then if i want to be able to change A1 to a new value while there are old values in A2:A5, and it will recalculate new values for A2:A5 based on new A1?

Comment: @lioliklev  I will update the code to make that happen..........................check back later.....................